# Expanding array along a dimension

Tags: julia

The following Python function expands an array along a dimension

```
def expand(x, dim,copies):
        trans_cmd = list(range(0,len(x.shape)))
        trans_cmd.insert(dim,len(x.shape))
        new_data = x.repeat(copies).reshape(list(x.shape) + [copies]).transpose(trans_cmd)
        return new_data

>>x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>x.shape
(2, 3)
>>x_new = expand(x,2,4)
>>x_new.shape
(2,3,4)
>>x_new
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6]]])
```

How can this function be replicated in Julia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a repeat -> reshape -> permutedims (like you have in numpy), I'd just do a reshape -> repeat. Accounting for the translation of row-major to column-major, it looks like this:

```
julia> x = [[1,2,3] [4,5,6]]
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6

julia> repeat(reshape(x, (1, 3, 2)), outer=(4,1,1))
4×3×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3

[:, :, 2] =
 4  5  6
 4  5  6
 4  5  6
 4  5  6
```

The tricky part about doing this efficiently in Julia is the construction of the tuples `(1, 3, 2)` and `(4, 1, 1)`. While you could convert them to arrays and use array mutation (like you convert it to a python list), it's far more efficient to keep them as tuples. `ntuple` is your friend here:

```
julia> function expand(x, dim, copies)
           sz = size(x)
           rep = ntuple(d->d==dim ? copies : 1, length(sz)+1)
           new_size = ntuple(d->d<dim ? sz[d] : d == dim ? 1 : sz[d-1], length(sz)+1)
           return repeat(reshape(x, new_size), outer=rep)
       end
expand (generic function with 1 method)

julia> expand(x, 1, 4)
4×3×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3

[:, :, 2] =
 4  5  6
 4  5  6
 4  5  6
 4  5  6

julia> expand(x, 2, 4)
3×4×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  1  1  1
 2  2  2  2
 3  3  3  3

[:, :, 2] =
 4  4  4  4
 5  5  5  5
 6  6  6  6

julia> expand(x, 3, 4)
3×2×4 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6

[:, :, 2] =
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6

[:, :, 3] =
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6

[:, :, 4] =
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6
```